# Get time between two dates

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to get the time between two dates in two different rows.

dataset:

| user | id | time | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user3 | 4 | 2021-02-01 14:00:00 | OUT |
| user1 | 2 | 2021-02-01 12:00:00 | OUT |
| user2 | 1 | 2021-02-01 10:00:00 | OUT |
| user1 | 2 | 2021-02-01 09:00:00 | IN |
| user2 | 1 | 2021-02-01 08:00:00 | IN |
| user3 | 4 | 2021-02-01 08:30:00 | IN |

What I am trying to obtain :

| user | id | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user3 | 4 | 07:30:00 |
| user1 | 2 | 03:00:00 |
| user2 | 1 | 02:00:00 |

The rows can be all mixed up since I dont know whenever a user will open (IN) or close (OUT) the job.

So far i tried to make a first query :

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-02' 
    ORDER BY date DESC;
```

And then I was thinking looping on the result array, and make the math from there, but I was wondering if there is anyway to do this in SQL only.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the result as out first then get the previous time from next row using Lead().
Though I am no expert in mariaDB but below query should work:

```
  with userresult as(
    SELECT *,lead(TIME,1)OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY STATUS DESC) previoustime,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by id order by status desc) rownum FROM USERS
where  DATE(date) BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-02' 
    )
    select user,id,timediff(time,previoustime)time from userresult where rownum=1
```

If your mariaDB version is lower than 10.2 you can try simple sql like below:

```
select username,id,timediff(time,(select max(time) from users u where status='in'and u.id=us.id ))
from users us where status='out'
```

Comment: forgot to mention phpMyAdmin, says "unrecognized statement type (near 'with')"

Comment: What's your mariadb version? is it lower than 10.2.1? Then this query will not work.

Comment: @acuz3r please let me know whether it worked or not and the version of your database.

Comment: It didnt work , here is the version, sorry for the confusion! : Server version: 5.6.41-84.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.1, @Kazi

Comment: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'Timediff' @Kazi

Comment: edited the answer. please check and let me know if you face any error.

Comment: I dont get any errors, but end up with negative numbers @Kazi

Comment: can u please upload the result. Actually i am browsing from mobile. can not verify the query. sorry for the inconveniyence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228308/discussion-between-acuz3r-and-kazi-mohammad-ali-nur).

Comment: I was able to solve my problem, thank you for your time and effort. @Kazi

Answer (score 1):

You can use comditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT user, id,
       Timediff( Max(case when status='OUT' then time end),
                 Min(case when status='IN' then time end) ) as diff
    FROM table 
    WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-02' 
    Group by user, id;
```

Comment: It works with only one problem, if the user close the job #1 (OUT) and works in another job #2 (IN & OUT) and then reopens the first job #1 (IN), it won't stop the 'timer', it will calculate from the frist IN to the last OUT for the job #1. @Popeye

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution:

```
   SELECT T1.id, T1.time AS INTime, T1_1.time AS OUTTime
   FROM T1 
   INNER JOIN T1 AS T1_1 ON (T1.id = T1_1.id AND T1_1.Status="OUT")
   WHERE T1.Status="IN";
```